# How to get the data from a column matching the condition of another column in a same table

Tags: sql, mysql

i'm trying to get the data from a table as shown below

[image]

i'm expecting the result as
[image]

tried the query as

```
SELECT DISTINCT(e1.empid) AS empid,
(SELECT e2.empstartedfrom FROM emp WHERE empprojectname='P1' LIMIT 1) AS P1projectstartedfrom, 
(SELECT e2.empstartedfrom FROM emp WHERE empprojectname='P2' LIMIT 1) AS P2projectstartedfrom,
(SELECT e2.empstartedfrom FROM emp WHERE empprojectname='P3' LIMIT 1) AS P3projectstartedfrom,
(SELECT e2.empstartedfrom FROM emp WHERE empprojectname='P4' LIMIT 1) AS P4projectstartedfrom,
(SELECT e2.empstartedfrom FROM emp WHERE empprojectname='P5' LIMIT 1) AS P5projectstartedfrom
FROM emp e1 INNER JOIN emp e2 ON e1.empid=e2.empid;
```

and i'm getting the result as
[image]

Comment: This is referred to as "PIVOT". Use search by this term.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select empid,
       max(case when empprojectname='P1' then empstartedfrom end) as P1projectstartedfrom,
       max(case when empprojectname='P2' then empstartedfrom end) as P2projectstartedfrom,
       max(case when empprojectname='P3' then empstartedfrom end) as P3projectstartedfrom,
       max(case when empprojectname='P4' then empstartedfrom end) as P4projectstartedfrom,
       max(case when empprojectname='P5' then empstartedfrom end) as P5projectstartedfrom
  from emp
group by empid;
```